# Pass an array via command-line to be handled with getopts()

Tags: bash

I try to pass some parameters to my .bash file.

```
terminal:

arr=("E1" "E2" "E3")
param1=("foo")
param2=("bar")
```

now I want to call my execute.bash file.

```
execute.bash -a ${arr[@]} -p $param1 -c param2
```

this is my file:

```
execute.bash:
while getopts ":a:p:c:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) ARRAY=${OPTARG};;
        p) PARAM1=${OPTARG};;
        c) PARAM2=${OPTARG};;
        \?) exit "Invalid option -$OPTARG";;
    esac
done

for a in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    echo "$a"
done

echo "$PARAM1"
echo "$PARAM2"
```

But my file only prints:

```
E1
foo
bar
```

Whats the problem with my script?

Comment: @Inian Thanks for the feedback. Reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding all values in the array using ${arr[@]} expands each value as a separate command-line argument, so getopt only sees the first value as the parameter to the "-a" option.

If you expand using ${arr[*]} then all of the array values are expanded into a single command-line argument, so getopt can see all of the values in the array as a single argument to the "-a" option.

There are a couple of other issues: you need to quote the values on the command line:

```
< execute.bash -a ${arr[@]} -p $param1 -c param2
> execute.bash -a "${arr[*]}" -p $param1 -c $param2
```

and use braces around ${OPTARG} in the getopt processing to make it an array assignment:

```
< a) ARRAY=${OPTARG};;
> a) ARRAY=(${OPTARG});;
```

after making these changes, I get this output:

```
E1
E2
E3
foo
bar
```

which I think is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with passing the array as one of the parameter for the `-a` flag. Arrays in `bash` get expanded in command line before the actual script is invoked.  The `"${array[@]}"` expansions outputs words separated by white-space

So your script is passed as

```
-a "E1" "E2" "E3" -p foo -c bar
```

So with the `getopts()` call to the argument `OPTARG` for `-a` won't be populated with not more than the first value, i.e. only `E1`. One would way to achieve this is to use the array expansion of type `"${array[*]}"` which concatenates the string with the default `IFS` (white-space), so that `-a` now sees one string with the words of the array concatenated, i.e. as if passed as

```
-a "E1 E2 E3" -p foo -c bar
```

I've emphasized the quote to show arg for `-a` will be received in `getopts()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts ":a:p:c:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) ARRAY="${OPTARG}";;
        p) PARAM1="${OPTARG}";;
        c) PARAM2="${OPTARG}";;
        \?) exit "Invalid option -$OPTARG";;
    esac
done

# From the received string ARRAY we are basically re-constructing another
# array splitting on the default IFS character which can be iterated over
# as in your input example

read -r -a splitArray <<<"$ARRAY"

for a in "${splitArray[@]}"; do
    echo "$a"
done

echo "$PARAM1"
echo "$PARAM2"
```

and now call the script with args as. Note that you are using `param1` and `param2` are variables but your definition seems to show it as an array. Your initialization should just look like

```
arr=("E1" "E2" "E3")
param1="foo"
param2="bar"
```

and invoked as

```
-a "${arr[*]}" -p "$param1" -c "$param2"
```

A word of caution would be to ensure that the words in the array `arr` don't already contain words that contain spaces. Reading them back as above in that case would have a problem of having those words split because the nature of `IFS` handling in `bash`.  In that case though use a different de-limiter say `|`, `#` while passing the array expansion.

Comment: This answer also works fine. But its a little longer than the accepted one. But Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If I want to export the array MY_ARRAY, I use at caller side:

```
[[ $MY_ARRAY ]] && export A_MY_ARRAY=$(declare -p MY_ARRAY)
```

... and at at sub script side:

```
[[ $A_MY_ARRAY =~ ^declare ]] && eval $A_MY_ARRAY
```

The concept works for parameters too. At caller side:

```
SUB_SCRIPT "$(declare -p MY_ARRAY)"
```

... and at at sub script side:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^declare ]] && eval $1
```

The only issue of both solution is, that the variable names are the same at both sides. This can be changed if replacing the variable name before expanding it.